# attr() returning undefined

Tags: jquery

I am setting a value in the attribute but it's giving me `undefined` when retrieving it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_field").attr("selectedvale", 'dsds')
  var aaa = $("#search_field").attr("selectedvale");
  alert(aaa)
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 20em
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="search_field">Address</label>
<input type='text' class='address_field' />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cq42h17p/

Comment: because it is undefined? in your fiddle there is no even a field with such an id, not to mention about attribute

Comment: please paste your code here

Comment: in your jsfiddle you have no element with the `id` `search_field` and have no element with the attribute `selectedvale` - what do you expect to get instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have no element with an id of `search_field` in your HTML, so

```
$("#search_field").attr(<anything>);
```

will always return `undefined` (and trying to set the `.attr` of an element which doesn't exist doesn't throw an error in jQuery - it just won't do anything).

Answer (score 0):

Your label haven't `id` called `search_field` . So you get `undefined`. Instead of `id` you can use direct markup like below and you get your value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label").attr("selectedvale", 'dsds')
  var aaa = $("label").attr("selectedvale");
  alert(aaa)
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 20em
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="search_field">Address</label>
<input type='text' class='address_field' />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".address_field").data("selectedvale", 'dsds')
  var aaa = $(".address_field").data("selectedvale");
  alert(aaa)
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 20em
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="search_field">Address</label>
<input type='text' class='address_field' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id="search_field" to the label or input

```
<label for="search_field" id="search_field">Address</label>
<input type='text' class='address_field' />
```

and do the rest